# Execute XML xrmtoolbox for Dynamics 365 getting error "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: xml, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml, xrmtoolbox

I want to create a view in my Dynamics 365 and I cant filter in the system so I use XRMToolBox to fetch the XML and customize it. So here is my code:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false" >
<entity name="opportunity" >
  <attribute name="name" />
  <attribute name="estimatedclosedate" />
  <attribute name="parentaccountid" />
  <attribute name="estimatedgrossprofit" />
  <attribute name="objections" />
  <attribute name="escalationstrategy" />
  <attribute name="conversionstrategy" />
  <order attribute="estimatedclosedate" descending="false" />
  <link-entity name="connection" from="record2id" to="opportunityid" alias="MyConnections" >
    <link-entity name="connectionrole" from="connectionroleid" to="record1roleid" alias="salesteamcategory" />
  </link-entity>
  <filter type="or" >
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="ownerid" operator="eq-userid" />
      <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
    </filter>
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition entityname="connection" attribute="record1id" operator="eq-userid" />
      <condition entityname="connection" attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
      <condition entityname="connectionrole" attribute="category" operator="eq" value="1001" />
    </filter>
  </filter>
  <attribute name="modifiedon" />
  <attribute name="estimatedvalue" />
  <attribute name="opportunityid" />
</entity>
</fetch>
```

And when I execute, this Error Message appeared.

[image]

Can anyone help me why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

This is some problem with that particular XrmToolBox plugin. Copied the query & tested in FetchXML builder.

Except these `attributes`, everything else is fine & successfully parsed. These may be custom attributes and they are missing prefix like `new_` or some other publisher specific.

```
  <attribute name="estimatedgrossprofit" />
  <attribute name="objections" />
  <attribute name="escalationstrategy" />
  <attribute name="conversionstrategy" />
```